# Boost PFC ICs not turning on

Tags: boost, power-factor-correction

I've built a boost PFC circuit on a PCB using the LT1249 controller, using the reference design guide provided by Analog Devices here: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1249fbs.pdf

I've scaled the reference design to achieve an output voltage of 60V with a 24VAC input:
[image]

The VCC is provided by a bench power supply which has the ground connected to the same ground as the resistor Rload.

However when I start the circuit with the bench power supply turned on, the output is essentially the input voltage filtered by the output capacitor meaning the IC is not switching on and operating as in the simulation.

I've checked every connection for potential faulty components or short circuit but regardless of if the IC is on or off the output will sit at roughly 33V. Can anyone help me understand where I could be going wrong

Comment: Is it *supposed* to modify the output voltage? It's the input current that PFC is most concerned about.

Comment: I would recommend you turn the PFC with the aux power supply set below the circuit UVLO and then turn the knob to increase the \$V_{cc}\$ and cross the turn-on level. Power-on synchronization can be important for some internal logic.

Comment: Which tools do you have for analysis? The value of R3 may be too high, the high voltage version has 1 Mohm there. What voltages do you see at VAout and CAout?